# vue-quill-editorのツールバーと入力欄が切り離せない

Tags: javascript, vue.js

vue-quill-editorのツールバーと入力欄を切り離して、ツールバーと入力欄の間に何か入れたいのですが、ツールバーと入力欄が切り離せません。
切り離す方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

```
<template>
  <div class="ml-5 mt-5">
    <div id="app">
      <quill-editor
        v-model="content"
        ref="quillEditor"
        :options="editorOption"
      ></quill-editor>
    </div>

    <p>{{ content }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Emit, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import 'quill/dist/quill.core.css';
import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import 'quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';
// @ts-ignore
import { quillEditor } from 'vue-quill-editor';
// @ts-ignore

@Component({
  components: {
    quillEditor,
  },
})
export default class Wysiwyg extends Vue {
  private content = '<h2>I am Example</h2>';
  private editorOption = {
    modules: {
      toolbar: [
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
        ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
        [{ header: 1 }, { header: 2 }],
        [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
        [{ script: 'sub' }, { script: 'super' }],
        [{ indent: '-1' }, { indent: '+1' }],
        [{ direction: 'rtl' }],
        [{ size: ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
        [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
        [{ font: [] }],
        [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
        [{ align: [] }],
        ['clean'],
        ['link', 'image', 'video'],
      ],
    },
  };
}
</script>
<style lang="scss">
code {
  padding: 2px 3px 1px;
  border: 1px solid var(--saf-0);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(var(--sk_foreground_min, 29, 28, 29), 0.04);
  color: #e01e5a;
}
.ql-container.ql-snow {
  border: none;
}

.ql-toolbar.ql-snow {
  border: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: できればお試しになったコードと一緒に記述していただけるとより回答が得やすいと思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。コードを記述しました。